# An algorithm to pair up words where a change has been made at a certain position?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Say I have a bag of random 'words' of a given length such as:

$$ADHBCBAB$$

Now I make another bag and copy all the words except for making a random change in the 5th position of each word. (Each word is changed in the exact same position to a random letter).

Now I give these two bags of words to someone and they have to

1) Determine in what position the change was made

2) Pair up the words from each bag

or

3) Determine that such a pairing is impossible (i.e. the first person cheated)

I think this problem is harder than it sounds when you don't know in what position the change was made in. Do you know if this can be translated into a well known problem with a known solution. And weather that solution is Polynomial time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to determine in general. Suppose you start with AB and BA, and the changed words are AA and BB. Which letter was changed?

Comment: Yes, indeed in that case the algorithm should quit and report there is no unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a bipartite graph, where the two sets of vertices are the two bags of words, and the edges connect those pairs of words that differ in the first letter position. Similarly construct a bipartite graph for the second letter position. the third, and so on.

Then look for perfect matchings in those graphs. You want only one of the graphs to have a perfect matching (otherwise it is ambiguous which letter position was changed), and that graph should have a unique perfect matching (else the paired up words are not uniquely determined).

There are various algorithms for finding maximal matchings in bipartite graphs. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching#Algorithms_for_bipartite_graphs). There are also algorithms for finding only perfect matchings, see for example [Hall's Marriage Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem). I don't know what the best algorithm is in your case.

Answer (score -1):

The edit distance algorithm is a popular algorithm for pattern matching. You can read about the algorithm on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance